# Fancybox not displaying correctly

Tags: asp.net, jquery, fancybox

I have a page, with a form, and I'd like to display a fancybox when a link is clicked on this page.

I have another working page with a fancybox on, which is fine, but on this page, the fancybox iframe seems to display using the incorrect height/width, and below the form on the page.

Although this is an ASP.Net site, I am using html only on this page, pretty much, as I need a fair amount of quick client side functions.

Here is my code:

```
<a href="../TravelManagement.aspx?period=monthly" class="iframe">Add Mileage Claim</a>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.iframe').fancybox({
        'frameWidth': 530,
        'overlayOpacity': 0.8,
        'overlayColor': "#000",
        'hideOnOverlayClick': false,
        'zoomSpeedIn': 1250
    });
});
```

There is also a jCarousel on this page, and the link itself is within a form.
Does anyone have any ideas, as i am stuck? I've googled a lot and found nothing.

Comment: obviously I paraphrased the code to show important bits, but if anyone wants more specific code, let me know. I know I didn't put the <script..> tag in :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got this working. It was due to the fact that the  tag was set with rel="text/css" when it needed "stylesheet".

You learn something new every day.